# name 'doc2vec' is not defined

Tags: python, word2vec, text-classification

I am trying to use doc2vec for text classification but after importing when i am trying to use it inside a function its says doc2vec in not defined. Please help me to identify which all libraries should I be installing to use doc2vec.

here I have 2 columns called Action(Text or sentences) and Category(actual tags)

```
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
import gensim
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
def label_sentences(corpus, label_type):
    labeled = []
    for i, v in enumerate(corpus):
        label = label_type + '_' + str(i)
        labeled.append(doc2vec.TaggedDocument(v.split(), [label]))
    return labeled
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.Action, df.Category, random_state=0, test_size=0.3)
X_train = label_sentences(X_train, 'Train')

Error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-d20e5f21684d> in <module>
----> 1 X_train = label_sentences(X_train, 'Train')

<ipython-input-53-bca3c695cfb6> in label_sentences(corpus, label_type)
      8     for i, v in enumerate(corpus):
      9         label = label_type + '_' + str(i)
---> 10         labeled.append(doc2vec.TaggedDocument(v.split(), [label]))
     11     return labeled

NameError: name 'doc2vec' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You imported `TaggedDocument` and not `doc2vec` but you used it this way `labeled.append(doc2vec.TaggedDocument(v.split(), [label]))`

So just use `TaggedDocument`  directly or if you don’t want that, just import doc2vec `from gensim.models import doc2vec`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help 
Only TaggedDocument works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
def label_sentences(corpus, label_type):
    labeled = []
    for i, v in enumerate(corpus):
        label = label_type + '_' + str(i)
        labeled.append(TaggedDocument(v.split(), [label]))
    return labeled
```

Answer (score -1):

from gensim.models import doc2vec 
or
labeled.append(TaggedDocument(v.split(), [label]))

works fine